# http request get method is returning null in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http

in my flutter app I'm using API request from server with http get method. but the response is returning null while printing the data inside the request it has data. how can I make an API call the right way?

JSON data

```
{
    "client": [
           {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Muhammed",
            "address": "Mexico",
            "tin_no": "123456789",
            "status": "1",
            "created_at": "2022-09-09T08:44:18.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-09-09T08:44:18.000000Z",
            "phones": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "client_id": "1",
                    "supplier_id": null,
                    "company_id": null,
                    "phone_number": "0911112222",
                    "email": "client@com.com",
                    "model": "Client",
                    "category": null,
                    "created_at": "2022-09-09T08:44:18.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-09-09T08:44:18.000000Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Salem",
            "address": "Torhailouch",
            "tin_no": "87654321",
            "status": "1",
            "created_at": "2022-09-10T05:54:47.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-09-10T05:54:47.000000Z",
            "phones": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "client_id": "2",
                    "supplier_id": null,
                    "company_id": null,
                    "phone_number": "0944551122",
                    "email": "client@com.com",
                    "model": "Client",
                    "category": "Sales",
                    "created_at": "2022-09-10T05:54:47.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-09-10T05:54:47.000000Z"
                }
            ]
        },]
}
```

Client model

```
class Client {
  List<Clients>? clients;

  Client({required this.clients});

  Client.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['clients'] != null) {
      clients = <Clients>[];
      json['clients'].forEach((v) {
        clients?.add(new Clients.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.clients != null) {
      data['clients'] = this.clients!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Clients {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? address;
  String? tinNo;
  String? status;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  List<Phones>? phones;

  Clients(
      {this.id,
      this.name,
      this.address,
      this.tinNo,
      this.status,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt,
      this.phones});

  Clients.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    address = json['address'];
    tinNo = json['tin_no'];
    status = json['status'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    if (json['phones'] != null) {
      phones = <Phones>[];
      json['phones'].forEach((v) {
        phones!.add(new Phones.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['address'] = this.address;
    data['tin_no'] = this.tinNo;
    data['status'] = this.status;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    if (this.phones != null) {
      data['phones'] = this.phones!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Phones {
  int? id;
  String? clientId;
  Null? supplierId;
  Null? companyId;
  String? phoneNumber;
  String? email;
  String? model;
  String? category;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;

  Phones(
      {this.id,
      this.clientId,
      this.supplierId,
      this.companyId,
      this.phoneNumber,
      this.email,
      this.model,
      this.category,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt});

  Phones.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    clientId = json['client_id'];
    supplierId = json['supplier_id'];
    companyId = json['company_id'];
    phoneNumber = json['phone_number'];
    email = json['email'];
    model = json['model'];
    category = json['category'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['client_id'] = this.clientId;
    data['supplier_id'] = this.supplierId;
    data['company_id'] = this.companyId;
    data['phone_number'] = this.phoneNumber;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['model'] = this.model;
    data['category'] = this.category;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}
```

API call is as follows

```
Future<List<Client>> fetchClient() async {
  Uri url = Uri.parse("${BASE_URL}client");

  var response = await http.get(url, headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $TOKEN',
  });

  var data = json.decode(response.body);
  print('...................$data...................');
  List<Client> clients = [];

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    for (var singleClient in data) {
      Client client = Client(clients: singleClient['clients']);

      clients.add(client);
    }
  }

  return clients;
}
```

main page

```
return FutureBuilder<List<Client>>(
        future: fetchClient(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text(index.toString());
              });
        });
```

Error thrown for this

`Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.`

what is the problem and how can I solve this?

Comment: inside fetchClient before if condition for statusCode, please print the status code?

Comment: @eamirho3ein the status code is 200.

Comment: your json should not be something like this: {
    "client":[{},{}]}?

Comment: @eamirho3ein that's the api that I have for the project.

Comment: could you please print("data = ${data["client"]}") in fetchClient inside if condition?

Comment: @eamirho3ein it prints `[{id: 1, name: Muhammed, address: Mexico, tin_no: 123456789, status: 1,.....`

Comment: @eamirho3ein sorry I forgot to include the `[ ]` in the json above. now it's fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `fetchClient()` to this:

```
Future<List<Clients>> fetchClient() async {
  Uri url = Uri.parse("${BASE_URL}client");

  var response = await http.get(url, headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $TOKEN',
  });

  var data = json.decode(response.body);
  print('...................$data...................');
  List<Clients> clients = [];

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    for (var singleClient in data["client"]) {
      clients.add(Clients.fromJson(singleClient));
    }
  }

  return clients;
}
```

and also in your `FutureBuilder` do this:

```
return FutureBuilder<List<Clients>>(
    future: fetchClient(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
           return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        default:
           if (snapshot.hasError) {
               return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
           } else {
               List<Clients> data = snapshot.data;
               return ListView.builder(
                   itemCount: data.length,
                   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                       return Text(data[index].name);
                   });
               });
            }
         }
    });
```

Comment: this worked tnx bro

Comment: one more thing how can I display the data on list view ?

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. @mobix

Comment: u used the <Clients> but the type is of <Client> so i used it `data[0].clients![index].name.toString()` but it throws an error of `Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value`

Comment: when I print `data[0]` it prints `Instance of 'Client'`, but when I access the clients it becomes null. `print(data[0].clients).

Comment: this has another error `type 'List<Client>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Clients>'`

Comment: You miss some place of my changes, replace  Client with Clients in every where in my answer.

Comment: tnx bro u were a big help now it's woring

Comment: I needed to assign all manually tho

Comment: not every where in your code, just in those place I mention in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check in your builder whether the data is finished loading. something like

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Text(index.toString());
    });
} else {
  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
}
```

Comment: I did `snapshot.data` but infinity circular progress no data.